# Asterisk system ignore some DTMF digits when it called by PABX phone

Tags: asterisk, dtmf, agi

I am using Asterisk E1 card on CentOS 6.2.

When I call on my asterisk system using a simple pstn or by a mobile phone, the call perfectly run. But when the same number has called by a PABX phone, the asterisk system ignored some digits.

I am using asterisk 1.4 and dahdi 2.4.

I have also tried the `dtmfmode = rfc2833` in the sip.conf file. Please some one hemp me resolve this problem.

eg: What actually Our system do, when some one call on our system, we ask for for a 14 digit registration id, and perform some operation on it and it work fine. But when some one call from their own PBX phone (or PABX or soft phone) and enter the registration id, then our system ignore some digits.

Comment: Just so I'm clear what you're asking;  when you say "PABX" phone, you mean an extension on your PBX, not an outside PBX, yes?

Comment: @MichelV69 What actually Our system do, when some one call on our system, we ask for for a 14 digit registration id, and perform some operation on it and it work fine. But when some one call from their own PBX phone (or PABX, A- autometic) and enter the registration id, then our system ignore some digits.

Answer (score 4):

I also had this problem some times ago this some PBXs.
this help for me:

relexdtmf=yes

*Example of my channel.conf:*

```
; SPAN 1-4 = E1 (1-15,17-31,32-46,48-62,63-77,79-93,94-108,110-124)
; ------------------

switchtype = euroisdn
; Type of Number (TON) for called number
pridialplan = local
; Type of Number (TON) for calling number
prilocaldialplan = private
signalling = pri_cpe
context = incoming
group = 1
immediate = no
overlapdial = yes

channel => 1-15,17-31,32-46,48-62,63-77,79-93,94-108,110-124

; activate this option if there are problems with dtmf detection
relexdtmf=yes
```

Comment: this only has an effect if the call comes from pstn.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you meant 'call from PBX internal extension' from 'call from their own PBX phone'.

I have faced issue like this. In my case the issue was with the phone. some old or broken IP phone failed to generate proper DTMF signals. Have you tried different phones like soft phones.

Comment: Actually I am facing the same problem with all PBX client, when they try to call they compliant. Did you solve your problem by any other configuration.

Comment: No, I didn't change configuration to solve it. Anyway, just to check, route your PBX extensions calls to PSTN through your E1 and get them to your PBX by dialling your E1 number. Check whats happening with that 14 digit thing.

Comment: When I call from a PSTN line, whole things goes fine.